# Show all users except profile being viewed (views, panel node)

Tags: 7, views, panels

I've got a view of type "users".  I have it filtered to a certain "role".  There are only 12 ppl in this role (it is for a calendar, and someone is sponsored each month).  When viewing a users profile I want to show a list of the other 11 below that user.  I currently have it listing all 12, I cant figure out a filter to exclude the current profile being viewed.

I have to be missing something easy

Answer (score 1):

the last checkbox on the settings of the contextual filter - exclude :) (under more)

Comment: HA! -- wooooooooow.  Thanks, Sorry to waste your time. I swear I looked at that screen 9,000 times.